# How can I get a value from a nested table in Power M Code

Tags: excel, powerbi, powerquery

I would like to get the `Max` value for [GroupIndex] and then use it to divide [Monthly Target] in order to create [Target].

The issue is I don't know how to get a single value from a nested table.

This is what I've tried so far:

1. Use `Table.RowCount()` like this:

   ```
   =Table.TransformColumns(Test, {"Count", each Table.AddColumn(_, "Target", each [Monthly Target]/Table.RowCount(_))})
   ```

> Error: We cannot apply operator / to types Number and Function.

[image]

2. I made a nested list and then asked for Max value for the operation:

   ```
   =Table.TransformColumns(Test, {"Count", each [GroupIndex]})

   =Table.TransformColumns(Test, {"Count", each Table.AddColumn(_, "Target", each [Monthly Target]/List.Max(Test2))})
   ```

> Error: We cannot convert a value of type Table to type List.

[image]

3. I tried using `List.Max()` to get the values and then use them to divide in the last line:

   ```
   =Table.TransformColumns(Test, {"Count", each List.Max([GroupIndex])})
   =Table.TransformColumns(Test, {"Count", each Table.AddColumn(_, "Target", each [Monthly Target]/Test2)})
   ```

> Error : We cannot apply operator / to types Number and Table.

[image]

I'd like to get this division before `Expand` all tables.

I appreciate any help. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would hit the **Expand** button for your **Count** Table-type column, but then choose the **Aggregate** option, then select only the columns **GroupIndex** and **Monthly Target**.

The UI will generate **List.Count** or **List.Sum** function calls (depending on the data type) - you can then edit those in the Formula bar to **List.Max**.  That should work fine for your particular scenario, but other List functions can be applied as required.

Comment: If I do this it will lose the other fields and I need them for a chart. Each nested table is a month. What I want is to get the daily `[Target]` on base in `[Monthly Target]/CountBusinnesDaysperMonth`. After a while finally I got something with `[Monthly Target]/Test2[Count]{0}` but I can't find how to iter `{i}`.

Comment: Just Duplicate the column Count (table-type) before the Expand step.  Then you can Aggregate as described above and also Expand in the usual way.

Comment: It wasn't necessary to create a new column. Instead I expanded the tables using the Aggregate option as you recommended me including the "missing" fields and then I got them using `List.Distinc` and `List.Max`. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

For future reference **Imke Feldmann** from another forum gave me this answer and it worked perfectly.

Hi David,

You cannot use the "each"-keyword twice in one command. Instead use the standard-function-syntax like this:

```
=Table.TransformColumns(Test, {"Count", each Table.AddColumn(_, "Target", (inner) => inner[Monthly Target]/Table.RowCount(_))})
```